# Getting char value from ComboBox in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, combobox, type-conversion

I need to get the selected value in a combobox as of a data type char.  I know how to get the selected item it's the conversion which I've got stuck on.  Any suggestions?

This is the combobox and it content:

```
      idCharCombo = new ComboBox<>();
      idCharCombo.getItems().addAll("A","B","G","H","L","M","P","Z");
```

Now i will be using this data in a method which passes an int and a char (bellow is the use of the method where the second element is still an object rather than a char):

```
      if (checkStaffMemberById(Integer.parseInt(idNoTxtFld.getText()), idCharCombo.getValue()) == true){
        AlertBox.display("ID Validation", "ERROR! ID Already Exists.");
```

hope i arranged adequately

Comment: What type of item is your `combobox`, and what do you mean by data type char ? Please be more specific, you speak about the primitive types ?

Comment: I have edited it, i hope it is more clear now, and thanks :)

Comment: So presumably this is a `ComboBox<String>`? Why don't you make it a `ComboBox<Character>` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your combo box appears to only hold single-character strings, and you want to treat them as `char`s, the most obvious thing to do is to use a `ComboBox<Character>` instead of a `ComboBox<String>`. I.e. replace your declaration, which presumably looks like

```
ComboBox<String> idCharCombo ;
```

with

```
ComboBox<Character> idCharCombo ;
```

and then you can do

```
idCharCombo.getItems().addAll('A','B','G','H','L','M','P','Z');
```

Then

```
idCharCombo.getValue()
```

will return a `Character` which will be autounboxed to a `char` as needed, so your method call

```
checkStaffMemberById(Integer.parseInt(idNoTxtFld.getText()), idCharCombo.getValue())
```

should work as-is.